# How to make an interactive window in which the image change was displayed?

Tags: python, image-processing

There is an image of 5 microcircuits, a function is called, the result of which is the blue coloring of the first microcircuit (accordingly, after the second function call, the second microcircuit is painted over and as a result we get an image with 5 blue microcircuits). The question is, how to create a window in which these image changes could be observed in real time and that it was written in Python?
[5 chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z88rQ.png)
[5 blue chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MXpR.png)

I tried to do this using tkinter, but I still didn't figure out how to make its window interactive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In real time with what? I mean what is causing them to change colour? Please add your latest/greatest code. What is this running on - arduino, Raspberry Pi, Linux desktop, Windows?

Comment: Maybe I put it wrong, in general I want the color change to be animated somehow. It is running on Windows. The color change is caused by a function that does sequential image processing of each chip and at the end fills the area inside the contour, for example, at the first iteration, the first chip, etc., until everything looks like the second image in my question)

Answer (score 1):

You can very simply use **OpenCV** and `cv.imshow()` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv

# Load image as BGR
im = cv.imread('z88rQ.png')

# Draw the window and wait up to 2s for user to press a key
cv.imshow("Image", im)
cv.waitKey(2000)

# Iterate over five points, one in each of the black objects
for y in [80,200,500,700,900]:

    # Fill next black item with blue
    cv.floodFill(im, None, (100, y), [255,0,0])

    # Draw the window and wait up to 2s for user to press a key
    cv.imshow("Image", im)
    cv.waitKey(2000)
```

[image]